# Gulp is so slow, why?

Tags: gulp, yeoman-generator

I am starting a new project using yeoman the popular https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular generator.
But gulp is very slow at simply launching on my macbook pro with 16G of RAM :

```
gulp serve
```

I have install gulpt to show the time each dependency takes to load, here is the result

```
 1  lodash.template (node_modules/gulp/node...node_modules/lodash.template/index.js)  768ms  ▇▇ 1%
 2  ./lib/template (node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/template.js)         775ms  ▇▇ 1%
 3  gulp-util (node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js)                      2.3s  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
 4  ./lib/src (node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js)               1.3s  ▇▇ 2%
 5  vinyl-fs (node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/index.js)                        1.9s  ▇▇▇ 3%
 6  gulp (node_modules/gulp/index.js)                                                  4.5s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 7%
 7  gulp-load-plugins (node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js)                       617ms  ▇ 1%
 8  /Applications/java/talend/git/test_gulp-angular/gulp/build.js (gulp/build.js)     681ms  ▇ 1%
 9  ./utils (node_modules/browser-sync/lib/utils.js)                                  816ms  ▇▇ 1%
10  ./services (node_modules/browser-sync/lib/services.js)                             1.2s  ▇▇ 2%
11  ./server (node_modules/browser-sync/nod.../node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js)  700ms  ▇ 1%
12  engine.io (node_modules/browser-sync/no...de_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js)  746ms  ▇ 1%
13  ./transports (node_modules/browser-sync...ine.io-client/lib/transports/index.js)  894ms  ▇▇ 1%
14  ./socket (node_modules/browser-sync/nod...odules/engine.io-client/lib/socket.js)  989ms  ▇▇ 2%
15  ./lib/ (node_modules/browser-sync/node_...modules/engine.io-client/lib/index.js)     1s  ▇▇ 2%
16  engine.io-client (node_modules/browser-...ode_modules/engine.io-client/index.js)     1s  ▇▇ 2%
17  ./manager (node_modules/browser-sync/no...dules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js)   1.2s  ▇▇ 2%
18  ./lib/ (node_modules/browser-sync/node_...modules/socket.io-client/lib/index.js)   1.6s  ▇▇▇ 3%
19  socket.io-client (node_modules/browser-...ode_modules/socket.io-client/index.js)   1.6s  ▇▇▇ 3%
20  ./lib (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js)              2.6s  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
21  socket.io (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/index.js)              2.6s  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
22  ./sockets (node_modules/browser-sync/lib/sockets.js)                               2.7s  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
23  accepts (node_modules/browser-sync/node...e-index/node_modules/accepts/index.js)  612ms  ▇ 1%
24  serve-index (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/serve-index/index.js)         935ms  ▇▇ 2%
25  send (node_modules/browser-sync/node_mo...rve-static/node_modules/send/index.js)  725ms  ▇ 1%
26  serve-static (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/serve-static/index.js)       864ms  ▇▇ 1%
27  ./utils.js (node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/utils.js)                         1.8s  ▇▇▇ 3%
28  finalhandler (node_modules/browser-sync...ct/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js)  616ms  ▇ 1%
29  ./proto (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js)             653ms  ▇ 1%
30  ./lib/connect (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js)     705ms  ▇ 1%
31  connect (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/connect/index.js)                 727ms  ▇ 1%
32  ./server (node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/index.js)                           2.9s  ▇▇▇▇ 5%
33  ./lib/browser-sync (node_modules/browser-sync/lib/browser-sync.js)                 8.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 13%
34  browser-sync (node_modules/browser-sync/index.js)                                  8.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 14%
35  gulp-util (node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js)           1.6s  ▇▇▇ 3%
36  gulp-protractor (node_modules/gulp-protractor/index.js)                            2.3s  ▇▇▇ 4%
37  /Applications/java/talend/git/test_gulp.../gulp/e2e-tests.js (gulp/e2e-tests.js)  10.5s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 17%
38  ./util/rc (node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/bower-config/lib/util/rc.js)         750ms  ▇ 1%
39  bower-config (node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/bower-config/lib/Config.js)        1.8s  ▇▇▇ 3%
40  through2 (node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/through2/through2.js)                 628ms  ▇ 1%
41  wiredep (node_modules/wiredep/wiredep.js)                                          2.9s  ▇▇▇▇ 5%
42  /Applications/java/talend/git/test_gulp...ulp/unit-tests.js (gulp/unit-tests.js)   2.9s  ▇▇▇▇ 5%
43  /Applications/java/talend/git/test_gulp-angular/gulpfile.js (gulpfile.js)         18.9s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 31%
44  transformers (node_modules/jade/node_modules/transformers/lib/transformers.js)    777ms  ▇▇ 1%
45  ./filters (node_modules/jade/lib/filters.js)                                      792ms  ▇▇ 1%
46  ./parser (node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js)                                         1.6s  ▇▇▇ 3%
47  jade (node_modules/jade/lib/index.js)                                              1.9s  ▇▇▇ 3%
48  gulp-util (node_modules/gulp-inject/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js)               1.7s  ▇▇▇ 3%
49  ./src/inject (node_modules/gulp-inject/src/inject/index.js)                        2.2s  ▇▇▇ 4%
50  gulp-inject (node_modules/gulp-inject/index.js)                                    2.2s  ▇▇▇ 4%
51  lodash.template (node_modules/gulp-jshi...node_modules/lodash.template/index.js)  856ms  ▇▇ 1%
52  ./lib/template (node_modules/gulp-jshin...ode_modules/gulp-util/lib/template.js)  993ms  ▇▇ 2%
53  gulp-util (node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js)               2.7s  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
54  jshint/src/cli (node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/jshint/src/cli.js)             1s  ▇▇ 2%
55  ./extract (node_modules/gulp-jshint/src/extract.js)                                1.1s  ▇▇ 2%
56  gulp-jshint (node_modules/gulp-jshint/src/index.js)                                  4s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 7%
57  lodash.template (node_modules/gulp-sass...node_modules/lodash.template/index.js)  918ms  ▇▇ 2%
58  ./lib/template (node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/template.js)    929ms  ▇▇ 2%
59  through2 (node_modules/gulp-sass/node_m...til/node_modules/through2/through2.js)  677ms  ▇ 1%
60  ./lib/noop (node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/noop.js)            710ms  ▇ 1%
61  gulp-util (node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js)                 2.8s  ▇▇▇▇ 5%
62  gulp-sass (node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js)                                        3.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇ 5%
63  gulp-util (node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js)         1.6s  ▇▇▇ 3%
64  postcss (node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer...e/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js)  628ms  ▇ 1%
65  ../data/prefixes (node_modules/gulp-aut...es/autoprefixer-core/data/prefixes.js)  866ms  ▇▇ 1%
66  autoprefixer-core (node_modules/gulp-au...autoprefixer-core/lib/autoprefixer.js)   2.2s  ▇▇▇ 4%
67  gulp-autoprefixer (node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/index.js)                          4s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 7%
68  gulp-util (node_modules/gulp-angular-filesort/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js)       2s  ▇▇▇ 3%
69  gulp-angular-filesort (node_modules/gulp-angular-filesort/index.js)                2.6s  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
70  request (node_modules/browser-sync/node...altunnel/node_modules/request/main.js)  674ms  ▇ 1%
71  localtunnel (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/localtunnel/client.js)        726ms  ▇ 1%
```

Any one has any idea to solve the problem ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your gulpfile. Would it be possible to refactor your gulpfile such that it only `require`s dependencies right before it needs them (e.g. in the tasks)?

Comment: The gulp files are the one generated by default by the yeoman gulp-angular generator without modification.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing.

Comment: do you have internet connection while running "gulp serve"? If not, setting online: true to browserSync.init may fix it.